# a newbie gcc compiler and c language question

Tags: c

when I'm trying to compile my c program it gives me this error warning: integer constant is too large for 'long' type

which refers to these lines

```
int barcode, a, b, c;
scanf("%d", &barcode);
a = barcode / 1000000000000;
b = barcode / 100000000000 % 10;
c = barcode / 10000000000 % 10;
```

and the rest is fine. I know I'm not supposed to use int for such a large number, any suggestions on what I should use? if I replace int with double what should the '%d' part be replaced with then?

Comment: got it to work now, thanks guys for the fast response, I'm going to bookmark and use this site more often!!!

Comment: Back when I worked with barcodes (a long time ago), we always treated them as strings, not numbers.

Comment: dydx: don't forget to mark an answer as "accepted".

Comment: will do, thank you. @Neil, I can't use strings/arrays/functions for my work.

Comment: Why on earth not? And you are using a function - scanf()

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use long longs instead of ints for integer values of that size, with the LL literal suffix:

```
long long barcode, a, b, c;
scanf("%lld", &barcode);
a = barcode / 1000000000000LL;
b = barcode / 100000000000LL % 10;
c = barcode / 10000000000LL % 10;
```

Comment: shouldn't it be
scanf("%lld", &barcode);

since barcodes are 13 digits?

Answer (score 0):

You should replace your int with long int, and prefix the constants with L

Like this:

```
long long unsigned int barcode;
barcode = 100000000LL;
printf("Barcode is %li", barcode);
```

Comment: So it would be:

long int barcode, a, b, c;
scanf("%il", &barcode);
a = barcode / 1000000000000L;
b = barcode / 100000000000L % 10;
c = barcode / 10000000000L % 10;

right?

13 digits is pretty big, what about long long instead?

long long barcode, a, b, c; what do I replace %d with?

Comment: nope, still no luck, i've added the L at the end of a = barcode / 1000000000000L;

and it still gives me integer constant is too large for 'long' type

Comment: Im sorry my bad, i forgot that in c/c++ long int has the same size as int. So it should be long long int. Ill update my post

Comment: The printf in your example will work, because the literal value you've given it is within the constraints of a 32-bit integer, but if the value stored in the long long exceeds MAX_INT, you will need to specify %lld to the printf specifier to make it output correctly on most compilers.

Answer (score 0):

Change the datatype to `long` as shown here

```
long barcode, a, b, c;
scanf("%ld", &barcode);
a = barcode / 1000000000000L;
b = barcode / 100000000000L % 10;
c = barcode / 10000000000L % 10;
```

Answer (score 0):

(if you like an answer, perhaps you could select one?)

Also, you might consider placing the barcode in a string instead. This way you can access the first 3 digits that you need more easily (if that is what you roughly want - note: you do want c to be the first two digits after the first digit, correct?)

```
char barcode[14];
int a, b, c;
scanf("%s", &barcode);
a = (int) (barcode[0] - '0');
b = (int) (barcode[1] - '0');
c = b * 10 + (int)(barcode[2] - '0');
```